# Eclipse won't show local git branch last commit

Tags: eclipse, git, eclipse-neon

The Eclipse-neon's inbuilt git plugin repository view was showing the last commit of my current local branch. Like so:

[image]

But it stopped showing the last commit all of a sudden:

[image]

I didn't make any changes at git preferences level or at the project level and my local develop branch is not detached.

And I couldn't find any setting in the Eclipse preferences which will turn on this.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there is a button in the repository view to enable/disable this, which I obviously oversaw it.

[image]